# imread() unable to identify existing image on Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

The file evidently exists, but imread() is unable to identify the image. Is there something I am missing? I'm still new to python and its respective libraries.

Code (Python 3.7.9)

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


from randomlyShiftChannels import *
from alignChannels import *
from utils import *

#Path to your data directory
data_dir = os.path.join('..', 'data', 'demosaic')

#List of images
image_names = ['balloon.jpeg','cat.jpg', 'ip.jpg',
            'puppy.jpg', 'squirrel.jpg', 'pencils.jpg',
            'house.png', 'light.png', 'sails.png', 'tree.jpeg'];

print('Evaluating alignment...')
for imgname in image_names:
    # Read image
    imgpath = os.path.join(data_dir, imgname)
    print("File exists:", os.path.exists(imgpath))
    img = imread(imgpath)
```

Output

```
File exists: True
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Spring2021\CS370\week 6\p2-release\code\evalAlignment.py", line 48, in <module>
    img = imread(imgpath)

  File "D:\Spring2021\CS370\week 6\p2-release\code\utils.py", line 14, in imread
    img = plt.imread(path).astype(float)

  File "C:\Users\dminn\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2246, in imread
    return matplotlib.image.imread(fname, format)

  File "C:\Users\dminn\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\matplotlib\image.py", line 1496, in imread
    with img_open(fname) as image:

  File "C:\Users\dminn\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\PIL\Image.py", line 2944, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '..\\data\\demosaic\\balloon.jpeg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your path to an absolute path, there are reasons we call it good practice

Sample code:

```
import os
os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt") #'C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.txt'
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it did not work. ```UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'D:\\Spring2021\\CS370\\week 6\\p2-release\\data\\demosaic\\balloon.jpeg'```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the identical issue using Spyder (Spyder 5.0.0 and 5.0.1).
No errors appeared when running the script from the command line.

Found workaround for Spyder: use pil_to_array() instead of imread()

```
from PIL import Image

img = pil_to_array(Image.open(imgpath))
```